# Super Constructor not passing values to render method

Tags: java, constructor, super

I made a class that can be called upon to to store the x and y values for my classes.  However, when I call the super constructor the values are not being passed.

This is where I make a new instance of the Player class in my main class.

```
p = new Player(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, this);
```

This is my class I am calling upon for my super constructor

```
public class GameObject {

public int x;
public int y;
public GameObject(int x, int y){    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
}
```

Here is my class calling the super constructor

```
public class Player extends GameObject implements EntityA{

private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;
Game game;
BufferedImage spriteSheet;
Rectangle bounds;

public Player(int x, int y, Game game){
    super(x, y);
    this.game = game;
    bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, Game.spriteSize, Game.spriteSize);
    spriteSheet = game.getSpriteSheet();
    System.out.println("x: " + this.x + " this.y: " + y);

}
```

Both x and y have values of zero.  I can see I am not using the call to the super constructor correctly.  Can someone tell me how this can be done.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Player` constructor, this line

```
System.out.println("x: " + this.x + " this.y: " + y);
```

is using the *`Player`* version of `x` and `y`, which are being ignored by your code, and therefore have the default initial values for ints, which is zero. I think you want to eliminate this

```
private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;
```

from your `Player` class, which would then cause your code to access the `GameObject` version of `x` and `y`, which is your goal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies not in the constructor, but in the fields of these classes. You define a `public int x` and `y` in `GameObject`, and also a `private int x` and `y` in `Player`.

The `GameObject.x` will get hidden by `Player.x`. However, the constructor for `GameObject` still sets `GameObject.x` to the given value. If you then try to query what `Player.x` is, then yes it is still zero.